# python Image module has no attribute after Image.open()

Tags: python, image

My code is like this
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWv55.png)

```
filename = 'X:'+os.sep+'premiere'+os.sep+'pic'+os.sep+'bg.png'
im = Image.open(filename)
print im
print type(im)
print dir(type(im))
```

and I can print type of im is PngImageFile.
[im's type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3LGD.png)

```
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=3508x2480 at 0x33BE550>
<class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
['_Image__transformer', '__class__', '__copy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__'........]
```

but I can't use any PngImageFile's attribute on im. Can someone tell me why, I'm confused.

Comment: Please copy your code and paste it in your question and use the formatting tools.

Comment: I have edit the question

Comment: you say "I can't use any PngImageFile's attribute on im" - what have you tried? what was the output? was there an error? for instance, what do you see when you do `im.getpixel((0,0))`?

Comment: It have no function. If I call a function, it tell me:TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: I try another image libiary named skimage, the same question.There must something wrong...

Comment: I don't know why, but it work well now....ths

Comment: check you dont accidentally reassign the value `im` or have two variables of the same name in different scopes. `im` is clearly not a tuple so there is something in your code you are not showing us. You should formulate a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will allow others to recreate and fix your issue.